# Hibernate Returning Multiple Outer Entities

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following entities:

- Survey
- Response
- ResponseQuestion
- Question

Survey has a one-to-one association with Response.
Response has a one to many association with ResponseQuestion, which has a many-to-one association back to the Response and a many-to-one association to the Question

I'm using the following query:

```
select r from Response r join fetch r.responseQuestion rq join fetch rq.question where r.survey.id = :survey_id
```

To fetch the response that corresponds to the survey. I'm expecting one Response entity on the outer layer, which has a List of 5 ResponseQuestion entities. However, what I'm getting back is a list of 5 Response objects, each of which have 5 ResponseQuestion objects.

I'm not sure why I'm getting 5 objects on the outside, all of which point to the same object in memory. There's only 1 row in the Response table. 5 rows in the ResponseQuestion table (all mapped to the one Response)

Could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use distinct, it should solve your problem.

select **distinct** r from Response r join fetch r.responseQuestion rq join fetch rq.question where r.survey.id = :survey_id

Comment: Simple solution. Don't know how I missed it. Thank you!